# Angry DM/GM site change - link updates?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hyperlinks

Someone kindly pointed out that the link in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/79721/28034) to an Angry DM post goes to what looks very much like a malicious domain squatter. Looks like he's moved to `theangrygm.com`. (There's more changes beyond the domain, e.g. article URLs have dropped the date references.)

I can try to track down the post I was linking to, but it seems to me this is something we should/could be systematic about, since I know there are quite a few such links scattered around the site.

Comment: I've edited your specific answer to update the link.

Comment: Good question highlighting this, was able to fix my answer with links to his old URL to use the new site.

Comment: I've finished updating the last of these links to their current location or to an archived version of the original page, so I've tagged the post as [status-completed].

Comment: Thank you everyone that helped out with updating the links!

Answer (score 13):

You can find all links on the site currently pointing to `angrydm.com` (the old website now used by a malicious domain squatter) by typing `url:"angrydm.com"` into the search bar. [Here's the list.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22angrydm.com%22)

I don't know that there's an easy way to fix these links (the links on the new site don't follow the exact same format) - or to intentionally break them to avoid leading people to a sketchy site. As far as I can tell, the only recourse is to manually fix all 41 answers and questions that include such links.

If people want to go ahead and update these links (you can generally find the new destination of the article by just googling "Angry GM" and then the article title), feel free to take the initiative! Just try to space it out a bit so as not to flood the front page.

---

**Note: All such links are now updated to their current location or to an archived version of the original page.**

Comment: Yeah... fixing's going to be a bit laborious. The articles tend to have the same title, but the url naming convention's not simply transferred from the old site to the new. If anything, though, that'll help rate-limit =)

Comment: @nitsua60 Not sure if angrydm posts were archived on archive.org (haven't checked) but if so, that's another option for fixes. Might be easier to automate the fixes in that case too due to similar urls.

Comment: We could ask ask angrydm himself about the urls.